# Playing old shockwave flash games on Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: flash, plugins

I know it's an old plugin, but there were a lot of fun games I recall really enjoying as a kid that ran on Shockwave Flash.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to install Shockwave Flash on Ubuntu 17.04 despite its age.

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative 1: Without a browser

<sup>As Adobe only provides a 64-bit standalone player this alternative is merely for 64-bit users (`uname -m` → `x86_64`).</></sup>

1. Download the [Adobe Flash standalone player](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html#fp15):

   ```
   wget https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the files:

   ```
   tar -xf flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Run the standalone player with

   ```
   ./flashplayer
   ```

   or call it directly with a `.swf` file:

   ```
   ./flashplayer /path/to/file.swf
   ```

You can move the `flashplayer` file to wherever you want, I recommend to save it in a folder like `~/scripts/` and define an alias like `alias flashplayer='~/scripts/flashplayer'` in your `~/.bash_aliases` file. This way it's stored where it belongs and you can still run it from every directory just by typing `flashplayer`.

#### Alternative 2: Using a browser

1. Install the Adobe Flash plugin from the *Canonical Partner sources*<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
   ```
2. Run the file in your browser by entering `file:///path/to/file.swf` in the address bar.

<sub>1 You may need to activate those source first with `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner" && sudo apt update`.</sub>

Comment: What would the command to run standalone on a 32 bit laptop?

Comment: @TomHancock Adobe doesn't provide a standalone player for 32-bit systems, now I don't know much about this matter but it seems like you need a virtual machine to run a 64-bit application in a 32-bit environment, see [Unix&Linux: Run 64 bit app on 32 bit system (Ubuntu)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118343/246819).

Comment: Okay so then in the browser, how will the adobe flash plugin help if it is for a shockwave game?

Comment: @TomHancock You didn't ask for a Shockwave game, but for a Shockwave **Flash** game, which should be supported by a regular Flash player (see e.g. [here](https://www.askdavetaylor.com/the_difference_between_flash_and_shockwave/) for an explanation) – which exactly is it? For Shockwave see [winehq.org](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3200).

Comment: Like DCR files...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1114354/how-to-view-adobe-shockwave-file-dcr-file-extension) helps?

Comment: I just tried wine...didnt seem to lag up my system as much as it should.  I simply installed netscape navigator and shockwave 11 (both off of oldapps.com, the newest version of shockwave was crashing on me) heres the final result.  There still is some game lag though, no idea where thats coming from.  
 Heres a photo of it running: https://tomhancock.000webhostapp.com/2017-09-28-223821_1024x768_scrot.png

Comment: I'd rather [download](http://cache.lego.com/eng/games/racers/supersonic/game.dcr) the game and run it locally (`file:///path/to/game.dcr`), but it may be as good as it gets.

Comment: I tried, it just skipped through the frames and wouldnt let me play the game.